# Is there any way to filter out certain ranges with NSLayoutManager?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, nslayoutmanager, nstextstorage

We have an `NSTextView` that could possibly contains large amounts of text. I'm using it to replace an `NSTableView`, which was far too slow when it was generating thousands of rows. We also have an `NSSearchField`, which used to apply its predicate to the table's array controller to narrow it down to only rows containing a given string. Now I want to do the same with the text view.

I tried applying a custom attribute to the found ranges in the `NSTextStorage`, then used the `NSLayoutManagerDelegate` method `-layoutManager:shouldGenerateGlyphs:properties:characterIndexes:font:forGlyphRange:` to set the glyph properties of the non-marked ranges to `NSGlyphPropertyNull`. This resulted in many errors:

```
_NSGlyphTreeGlyphRangeForCharacterRange missing glyphs 1
```

And it brought the app to its knees. Is there some better way to filter the display of the textStorage and only draw the paragraphs we found?

For now, it has to work on 10.10. Bleh.

Comment: Thousands of rows in a table view shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It is. Filling a text view with the text takes a fraction of a second, where reading that same file and breaking it into thousands of substrings and adding them to an array controller takes ~10 seconds. I asked a question about NSLayoutManager, not surmises about tables.

Comment: The conversion of the data is too slow, not the table view.

Comment: No it is not. Quit assuming you can see how my code is behaving. I said "AND adding them to an array controller". Do you have anything constructive to offer about my actual NSLayoutManager question?

Comment: I don't want future readers to think that `NSTableView` can't display thousands of rows.